# Given a dataset, how to test your model against the test set if you used StratifiedKFold and standardized train and validation sets per fold?

Tags: python, cross-validation, standardization

I couldn't find an answer to the following issue and I kinda feel stuck...

I have a dataset and I want to split it as follows:

- 90% for train and validation
- 10% for test

Now, I want to use `StratifiedKFold()` on the 90%. Let's say I want 10 folds. I do the loop, get the indices, get the training and validation sets, use the `StandardScaler()` for each fold separately, train the model on each fold, get the average accuracy.

After I do all of these, how should I use the 10% left for testing, given the fact it wasn't standardized? What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: To answer my question, I think I'm missing sleep. Is the correct answer the usual standardization as I did it per each fold?

Answer (score 0):

You have to normalize at each loop/fold your test set with the SAME normalization you applied to your training set, so something like this:

```
normalization = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)

X_train = normalization.transform(X_train)
X_test  = normalization.transform(X_test)
```

If you don't apply the same normalization to the test set then you will have fundamentally modified your test data.